# Differences when using shared_ptr and unique_ptr to point to an array?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

In C++11, I just found that it looks like there are some differences between `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` when they are used to allocate an array. I would like to get confirmation if what I found is correct.

I must use `<int []>` for `unique_ptr` but `<int>` for `shared_ptr` only:

```
unique_ptr<int []> myUniquePtr = unique_ptr<int[]> ( new int[100]);

shared_ptr<int> mySharedPtr = shared_ptr<int>( new int[100]);
```

For `unique_ptr`, I do not need to overload a `delete` functor/lambda func for a pointer to an array:

```
unique_ptr<int []> myUniquePtr = unique_ptr<int[]> ( new int[100]); //should be good enough
```

but I will for `shared_ptr`:

```
shared_ptr< int> mySharedPtr = shared_ptr<int> ( new int [100], [](const int* p){delete [] p;});
```

To access an element in the array through a smart pointer, with `unique_ptr` I can use the regular way `[index]`, but with `shared_ptr` I cannot do that:

```
myUniquePtr[10] = 100; // should be OK
```

but I need

```
mySharedPtr.get()[10] = 100;
```

Could you please confirm if the above statements are correct? Will it be any different in C++14?

Comment: `uinque_ptr` has a specialisation for array types, wherefore it can discern whether it needs to use `delete`or `delete[]`without you providing the deleter. However, if you need to allocate an array and have the respective accessors, you probably want to use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Comment: You may want to look up `make_unique` and `make_shared`.

Answer (score 3):

The different behaviour can be explained by the fact that there is a specialisation `template <class T, class Deleter> class unique_ptr<T[], Deleter>` for the `std::unique_ptr`. This specialisation allows for different behaviour when using an array type rather than a scalar type.

If you look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr, you can also see that only the array variant implements `operator []`, which allows you to do the access described in 3.

If you take the documentation at https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr, you see that there is no special handling for `T[]` in case of `std::shared_ptr`. Therefore, you need to retrieve the raw pointer before you can use the "standard" array access. Also, it cannot decide when to use `delete` and when `delete[]`, so you need to provide a deleter if you do not pass an object that can be deleted by the standard deleter.

Afaik, there are no changes in this behaviour in C++14.

Comment: C++17 added `[]` overload for array access with shared_ptr